# JVM class loader visibility/resolution issues finding custom class

Tags: annotations, jvm, osgi, classloader, resolution

I try reformulate the question, because probably previous ones didn’t make too much sense.
Background:
sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy thrown by cxf webservice getPort() in karaf osgi because there is a class in the annotation of web method loaded by a custom class loader (and not the application classloader).
I don’t really want a solution here, because maybe it is just a cxf bug, I just want to understand how can this happen. So my question is in short:
Is it possible to configure the application classloader which loads classes from the CLASSPATH to instead contact  my custom class loaders? If I put the missing class in the lib folder, then the api call finds it, but that is not what I want, I want it use the bundles class loader.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you did and what error you got? (Ideally with an example). The way you formulated the question makes it a bit hard to understand.

Comment: OK, sorry, I'll try to reformulate the question :) See editet part.

Answer (score 0):

In OSGi the classloader of each bundle contains the classes of that bundle. It can also resolve classes from all declared Import-Package packages. It resolves these classes by delegating to the classloader of the respective bundle that offers the export and that was selected during resolve as a provider of that package.

So in OSGi normally that same class is only loaded by one classloader. The classloader of the bundle that contains the class. All other classloaders delegate to it if they have correct imports.

As CXF always also consults the classloader of your bundle you might try to make sure you import the package of the class that was not found.

In OSGi it should not happen that something is not yet loaded as each bundle is resolved before its code is executed (provided you are not using things like optional imports or dynamnic imports).

If you use custom classloader then all odds are off and you will need to provide an example with your code.

Comment: No I am not using my own custom class laoder. Basically what happens is that sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray( at the bottom of the cxf stacktrace fails to locate my class in a bundle. So it seems cxf does not consult it (it consults the application class loader). But it is in a bundle (other bundles import it and it has an export). How to tell cxf to consult it?